# An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request in C# project

Tags: c#

I am getting the above error when I run my project, the stack is:

```
[ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.]
System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.InternalFree(IntPtr handle) +0
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Free() +77
   System.Web.Util.GCUtil.UnrootObject(IntPtr pointer) +70
   System.Web.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) +594
   System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +247
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +643
```

Any idea what could this be?

Comment: is it from a `Response.End()`? Can you provide a little more context?

Comment: Go to exception details and check for more information. There's a chance you get the real exception in the `Inner exception` part

Comment: Actually this occurs when I try to open a connection with my database, var datab = db.Users; I get the above error with stack trace.

Comment: The stacktrace does not indicate any database connection, look at inner-exception as suggested by Alex. Note that ASP.NET performs resume steps within in the pipeline using different threads, thus you cant bargain to get the same thread for storing thread static data within the context of an operation.